# How I can open a different recycler view activity for each google map marker I place

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I am getting `lng` and `lat` from a JSON file, to place my markers. Now I created an on click info window listener to open a new activity to show more information. I want that each marker shows different information when been clicked, how can I so that.

Right now I only can show the same `recyclerview` for each marker

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what kind of information you will show on the following screen and where do you get the information but the simplest idea to differentiate each marker click can be done like this:

Keep references of your marker objects and add the following code to your map activity

```
 @Override
public boolean onMarkerClick(final Marker marker) {

Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,RecyclerViewActivity.class);
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
String infoArrayString;

if (marker.equals(myMarker1)) 
{

//Assuming you have JSONArray of information to show on the next screen

infoArrayString = markerJson1.toString();
bundle.putString("info",infoArrayString);

}else if(marker.equals(myMarker2){

//info for marker2

}
intent.putExtras(bundle);
startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I generate my markers with a for loop so I only have myMarker1

Comment: You can still keep references of them. I suggest you to share your code